# Running multiple $ssh->exec commands with $ssh->write in phplibsec

Tags: php, bash, ssh

I am running phplibsec to run a password change script on my server. I currently have three passwords I need to change. Currently these are changed with a bash script which is run by an $ssh->exec command. However due to growing complications, I need to run each of these individually.

I have started to work on getting these to run in phplibsec and have found that one password will change, but the script will stop and I am not sure why.

Here is what I have working:

```
$ssh->enablePTY();      
    $ssh->exec('htdigest /etc/apache2/.passwd "Authenticated Users" ' . $username);
    $ssh->read('password:');
    $ssh->write("$newpass\n");
    $ssh->read('password:');
    $ssh->write("$newpass\n");
```

However, when i try to write another successive command, it simply fails no matter what the command.

Here is what I need eventually:

```
    $ssh->enablePTY();      
    $ssh->exec('htdigest /etc/apache2/.passwd "Authenticated Users" ' . $username);
    $ssh->read('password:');
    $ssh->write("$newpass\n");
    $ssh->read('password:');
    $ssh->write("$newpass\n");

    $ssh->exec('htpasswd /etc/squid3/squiddb ' . $username);
    $ssh->read('password:');
    $ssh->write("$newpass\n");
    $ssh->read('password:');
    $ssh->write("$newpass\n");

    $ssh->exec('passwd ' . $username);
    $ssh->read('password:');
    $ssh->write("$newpass\n");
    $ssh->read('password:');
    $ssh->write("$newpass\n");
```

It seems that as soon as the read/writes are introduced, then it's not possible to run anymore exec commands. I am not sure, and have not been able to find a way to exit from this while still being able to execute.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This maybe of interest to you: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/506